# Populating Database from Api Response in Php Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, api, guzzle

please i had been having headache in trying to access this Api Response from Guzzlehttp, the Format is the Problem here, i dont understand i need help.

Hello Guys! please i had been having headache in trying to access this Api Response from Guzzlehttp, the Format is the Problem here, i dont understand i need help.

**this is the code**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Country;
use App\Globas;

class DataController extends Controller
{
public function getClient(){
  $client=new Client();
  $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary');
  $data= json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);

//delete all row in the database table
Globas::truncate();
Country::truncate();
  foreach($data as $da){
   Globas::create($da);
   Country::create([
       'Country'=> $data['Country'],
       'CountryCode'=>$data['CountryCode'],
       'Slug'=>$data['Slug'],
       'Date'=>$data['Date'],
       'NewConfirmed'=>$data['NewConfirmed'],
        'TotalConfirmed'=>$data['TotalConfirmed'],
           'NewRecovered'=>$data['NewRecovered'],
              'TotalRecovered'=>$data['TotalRecovered'],
               'NewDeaths'=>$data['NewDeaths'],
               'TotalDeaths'=>$data['TotalDeaths']
   ]);
return $data;
  }
}

}

**This is the Response** 

{"Global":

{"NewConfirmed":259470,"TotalConfirmed":19636772,"NewDeaths":5457,"TotalDeaths":726765,"NewRecovered":201182,"TotalRecovered":11938458},"Countries":[{"Country":"Afghanistan","CountryCode":"AF","Slug":"afghanistan","NewConfirmed":39,"TotalConfirmed":37054,"NewDeaths":5,"TotalDeaths":1312,"NewRecovered":57,"TotalRecovered":25960,"Date":"2020-08-09T17:38:36Z","Premium":[]},

......

{"Country":"Zimbabwe","CountryCode":"ZW","Slug":"zimbabwe","NewConfirmed":124,"TotalConfirmed":4575,"NewDeaths":0,"TotalDeaths":102,"NewRecovered":71,"Total``Recovered":1416,"Date":"2020-08-09T17:38:36Z","Premium":[]}],"Date":"2020-08-09T17:38:36Z"}


**Country Model**

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
   protected $fillable=['Country','CountryCode','Slug','Date',
   'NewConfirmed', 'TotalConfirmed','NewRecovered','TotalRecovered','NewDeaths','TotalDeaths'];
}

**Globas Model**

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Globas extends Model
{
   protected $fillable=['NewConfirmed','TotalConfirmed','NewRecovered','TotalRecovered','NewDeaths','TotalDeaths'];
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a variable to the return of `Global::create()` and `Country::create()`. Like so `$global = Global::create(...)` the run `$global->save()` to store it in the database.

Edit: Based on you latest reply, your iterating over the data, when you shouldn't because the data returned is not an array. For globals, you don't need to iterate. You can do something like this:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary');
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(),true);

$globals=Globas::create([
    'NewConfirmed'=>$data['NewConfirmed'],
    'TotalConfirmed'=>$data['TotalConfirmed'],
    'NewRecovered'=>$data['NewRecovered'],
    'TotalRecovered'=>$data['TotalRecovered'],
    'NewDeaths'=>$data['NewDeaths'],
    'TotalDeaths'=>$data['TotalDeaths']
]);

$globals->save();

foreach($data['Countries'] as $country) {
     $country = Country::create([
               'Country'=> $country['Country'],
               'CountryCode'=>$country['CountryCode'],
               'Slug'=>$country['Slug'],
               'Date'=>$country['Date'],
               'NewConfirmed'=>$country['NewConfirmed'],
               'TotalConfirmed'=>$country['TotalConfirmed'],
               'NewRecovered'=>$country['NewRecovered'],
               'TotalRecovered'=>$country['TotalRecovered'],
               'NewDeaths'=>$country['NewDeaths'],
               'TotalDeaths'=>$country['TotalDeaths']
           ]);

    $country->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside foreach you should refer to $da variable, not $data in that place:

```
Country::create([
       'Country'=> $data['Country'],
       'CountryCode'=>$data['CountryCode'],
       'Slug'=>$data['Slug'],
       'Date'=>$data['Date'],
       'NewConfirmed'=>$data['NewConfirmed'],
        'TotalConfirmed'=>$data['TotalConfirmed'],
           'NewRecovered'=>$data['NewRecovered'],
              'TotalRecovered'=>$data['TotalRecovered'],
               'NewDeaths'=>$data['NewDeaths'],
               'TotalDeaths'=>$data['TotalDeaths']
   ]);
```

another point is that countries is an array too, so you should probably make another foreach for countries.

[image]

```
foreach ($data['Countries'] as $country)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am get the ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined index: NewConfirmed

**when i did something like this**

```
 foreach($data['Countries'] as $country){


     $counter=   Country::create([
               'Country'=> $country['Country'],
               'CountryCode'=>$country['CountryCode'],
               'Slug'=>$country['Slug'],
               'Date'=>$country['Date'],
               'NewConfirmed'=>$country['NewConfirmed'],
                'TotalConfirmed'=>$country['TotalConfirmed'],
                   'NewRecovered'=>$country['NewRecovered'],
                      'TotalRecovered'=>$country['TotalRecovered'],
                       'NewDeaths'=>$country['NewDeaths'],
                       'TotalDeaths'=>$country['TotalDeaths']
           ]);

            }


   foreach($data as $da){
    $globals=Globas::create([
        'NewConfirmed'=>$da['NewConfirmed'],
        'TotalConfirmed'=>$da['TotalConfirmed'],
                       'NewRecovered'=>$da['NewRecovered'],
                          'TotalRecovered'=>$da['TotalRecovered'],
                           'NewDeaths'=>$da['NewDeaths'],
                           'TotalDeaths'=>$da['TotalDeaths']
    ]);
    
    }
}
```